# PHP Soap Header help

Tags: php, soap, nusoap, soap-client, soapheader

I have a fairly simple php/soap header question.

Here's what I need.

```
<ns1:Identity token="123456789"></ns1:Identity>
```

Here's what I get...

```
<ns1:Identity><item><key>token</key><value>123456789</value></item></ns1:Identity>
```

using this code...

```
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://qpricer.com/Services/Pricing','Identity',array('token'=> '123456789'));
$client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
```

Using soapui, I have narrowed my issue down to this right here.

How do I go from the second one to the first one?

An help would be greatly appreciated, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this was the only header I had to set, I was able to fix it using the following code.

```
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.qpricer.com/Services/Pricing','Identity token="123456789"',null);
```

This produced the following XML

```
<ns1:Identity token="123456789"/>
```

and it worked!